# Click icon ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have a class `MyAdapter` which extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter`.
I want an item with a `TextView` and an `ImageButton` in a `ConstraintLayout`.

The function:

```
 public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = (ConstraintLayout) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.constraint, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_mytext);
        ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_my);
        if (tv != null) tv.setText("MyText");
        if (imgBtn != null) imgBtn.setOnClickListener(.....);
        return convertView;
    }
```

The layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tv_mytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_item_black"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img_btn_my"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_expand_more" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What is the best way to:

- have a click listener on an item
- have a click listener only on `imgButton`

If I add a click on `imgButton`, the item click listener doesn't work.

Comment: please post your layout

Comment: OK, it's done  with textview and imagebutton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To let the item clickable after add a click on  `imgButton`, declare this into **ConstraintLayout**

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```